# Existence of tubular neighborhood of singular complex subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective manifold and let $Y$ be a closed subvariety of $X$ with $y\in Y$ a fixed point. Does there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $Y$ such that $\pi_1(Y,y)\to \pi_1(U,y)$ is an isomorphism? Moreover, can we expect a stronger result: there exists a tubular neighborhood $U$ of $Y$ such that $Y$ is a deformation retract of $U$?

The above questions have positive answers when $Y$ is smooth. But I don't know the singular case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Theorem 4.5 in [Hofmann's thesis](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/63851/krhofman_1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) grants the existence of a pair of triangulations $(T,T') \cong (X,Y)$ for any semialgebraic variety $X$ and subvariety $Y$. Regular neighborhoods always exist for subcomplexes of simplicial complexes by subdivision techniques.

Comment: @ Connor: many thanks for your answer. That is really an impressive result. Theorem 4.5 by Hofmann said that $Y$ is the union of open simplices of $T$. Could you explain briefly what is your definition of regular neighborhoods of $Y$ and why it deforms retract into $Y$ please?

Comment: I believe if $Y$ is closed this "union of open simplices" is equivalent to being a subcomplex. For regular neighborhoods, I would check out [Section 3](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/pltop.pdf) of these notes by Bryant and in particular Theorem 3.5 which shows regular neighborhoods in the PL world are mapping cylinders, which implies they deformation retract.